# Ember.js and ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Looking at ArrayController at the moment I came across two ways of implementing them:

1. http://awardwinningfjords.com/2011/12/27/emberjs-collections.html
2. http://trek.github.com

From what I see are the differences mainly in

- ArrayController.create vs ArrayController.extend
- In the demo from trek, the data is loaded in the model whereas in the Twitter example it is loaded in the controller.
- For the option of Twitter, I wonder how to do the routing.

Which one of the twos should one use as a common pattern for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trek's post reflects the most current best practices as of September 2012. It would be better to follow Trek's examples than the one in the blog post about Twitter.

Comment: and this best practice is still valid or is the twitter one the newer approach?

Comment: Trek's is better to follow. I'll clarify my answer

Comment: Thanks! Now I need to figure out how to resolve the bug when clicking on a contributer and then go back to 'all contributors' so that the data is not duplicated.